# JPA - lazy load unidirectional OneToMany not working with discriminator

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to have a oneToMany relationship between Visit and CrewMember.
This CrewMember is a "type of person" and has some specific attributes that are not needed for other types (Passenger for example) -> hence the inheritance

This oneToMany relationship has to be lazy loaded, but when I then get the crewMembers it seems as if my join doesn't take the discriminator into account.

Visit class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VISIT")
public class Visit {
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "VISIT_ID")
  private List<CrewMember> crewMembers;
}
```

CrewMember class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "CREW")
public class CrewMember extends Person {
  @Column(name = "CREW_NUMBER")
  private Integer number;
}
```

Person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_ON_BOARD")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_PERSON_ON_BOARD")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Person {
  ...
}
```

I've created a method to find those crewMembers like this:

```
@Stateless
public class PeopleOnBoardRepositoryBean implements PeopleOnBoardRepository {

  @Override
  public List<CrewMember> findCrewMembers(long visitId) {
    TypedQuery<Visit> query =  em().createQuery("SELECT v FROM Visit v JOIN fetch v.crewMembers WHERE v.id = :visitId", Visit.class);
    query.setParameter("visitId", visitId);
    Visit visit = query.getSingleResult();
    return visit.getCrewMembers();
  }
}
```

But the result always contains ALL the persons (crewMembers, passengers) instead of only the crewMembers.. Why is that and what am I doing wrong?

If I'm trying to do it the "normal way which I would think that should work" like:

```
public List<CrewMember> findCrewMembers(long visitId) {
    TypedQuery<Visit> query =  em().createQuery("SELECT v FROM Visit v  WHERE v.id = :visitId", Visit.class);
    query.setParameter("visitId", visitId);
    Visit visit = query.getSingleResult();
    return visit.getCrewMembers();
}
```

then I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: be.fgov.health.msw.domain.visit.Visit.crewMembers, no session or session was closed
```

**EDIT**:

After adding:

```
Visit visit = query.getSingleResult();
visit.getCrewMembers.size();
return visit.getCrewMembers();
```

I've got the LazyInitializationException fixed. This was needed to fetch all the crewMembers. Otherwise I was just passing a pointer to the arrayList without prefetched elements hence the LazyInitializationException.

The problem with the discriminator is still there though.. I'm getting ALL the persons instead of only the crewMembers. I've also tried adding:

```
@ForceDiscriminator
```

on my Person class but this doesn't change anything. I've read that on http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/08/26/hibernate-why-should-i-force-discriminator/

**EDIT 2:**

I've "fixed" (workaround) the discriminator column by adding:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "VISIT_ID")
@Where(clause="TYPE_PERSON_ON_BOARD = 'CREW'")
private List<CrewMember> crewMembers;
```

The @Where fixes this but I actually find this extremely ugly. Isn't there any other way to do this?

Comment: The Discriminator isn't really related to this problem.  It's more an issue with how Hibernate supports JPA transactions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the persistence-unit transaction-type set to?

Comment: @Powerlord The Discriminator is the problem. The transactions are managed by the application server (jBoss 7.1.1). I've got it working by calling visit.getCrewMembers().size() to initialy load all the crewMembers. Otherwise they aren't loaded yet hence the LazyInitializationException. The problem on the other hand is that I'm still getting ALL types of persons instead of only the crewMembers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the entity bean within the boundary of the transaction (session) otherwise the results are dettached resulting lazy exception

Comment: See edit. The transaction "problem" is fixed, but I'm still having the initial discriminator problem.